# Evaluate value of string as a condition and execute IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, evaluation

I hope my title is not confusing. What I need is:

I have a condition in a string:

```
$user_rights = "$USER[ADMIN] || $USER[RIGHT1] || $USER[RIGHT2]";
```

var_dump($user_rights)

```
string(11) "0 || 0 || 0"
```

I would like to put the variable $user_rights into the IF statement like this

```
if($user_rights)
```

and I want it to work the same way like

```
if($USER[ADMIN] || $USER[RIGHT1] || $USER[RIGHT2])
```

Is it possible?

Comment: (Why) does it have to be a string? Why do you not use an array containing the rights, that you then can simply loop over to check if the needed one(s) is in there?

Answer (score 0):

Tty this:-

```
$string = "$USER[ADMIN] || $USER[RIGHT1] || $USER[RIGHT2]";
//convert this to array
$array = explode("||",$string);

//if you know inside string only three variable
if($array[0] || $array[1] || $array[2] ){
    //your condition
}
```